# Apple developer id for IBM Worklight ApplicationCenter

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Do I still need an Apple Developer ID for deploying applications on iOS devices using IBM Worklight Application Center?
Thanks!

Comment: Native apps? To the App Store or through Enterprise Distribution?

Comment: Enterprise Distribution. Mainly HTML5 apps but hybrid also...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you get both Apple Developer (https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios) and iOS Developer Enterprise (https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise) accounts.  These are separate accounts at Apple. The first will support you during development and testing and the later allows you to sign applications for internal use by employees of your company.

The cost of these licenses is very small compared to most development tools and you will save a lot of time by just working with Apple's system the way they want you to.

Worklight's Application Center provides good tools for managing the distribution of your internal apps, but they have to be signed properly with the Apple accounts or you won't be able to deploy them to iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. Any iOS application requires you to be a registered Apple Developer, and have you set-up everything that is required for iOS development. This is not about to change and out of the hands of Worklight. Familiarize yourself with developing for iOS.